# A formula for $\int\limits_0^\infty (\frac{x}{e^x-1})^n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, indefinite-integrals

The Stirling numbers of the first kind $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ are defined by 
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}x^k:=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ .

Which proof exists for

$$\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^n dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\begin{bmatrix} n \\ n-k+1 \end{bmatrix}\zeta(k+1)\quad,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

?

I am also looking for literature where a proof is written, so that it isn’t necessary to write one down here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your identity is just a consequence of integration by parts, together with the identity:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{e^x-1}\,dx = k!\cdot\zeta(k+1)\tag{1} $$
that simply follows by expanding $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ as $e^{-x}+e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}+\ldots$
 So the whole point is just to compute
$$ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{1}{(e^x-1)^n} \tag{2}$$
by recalling, for instance, that by stars and bars we have:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{m+n}{n}x^n.\tag{3} $$

Comment: @user90369: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

A more general formula holds. Take a look at formula (10) in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042796001677) by Adamchik for $p=n+1$ and $a=n$. The hypergeometric function on the l.h.s. can be written as the integral given just before formula (16). By letting $x=\ln(1/t)$ one can easily obtain your integral.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I know papers of Adamchik but this is new for me.